# Laravel cookies not being set in browser

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cookies, axios

I am currently developing a website with **Laravel** as **REST API** and **React** as the front-end.I encounter a problem when i tried to login in the front-end side, the response cookie is being sent correctly but it is not set in the browser. For cors, i use **Fruitcake\Cors**. I am thankful if you could really help me with this problem, i've been trying to solve it for several hours.

**Front-end Code When Making Request**

```js
const login = async (payload) => {
try {
 const response = await axios.post("/auth/admin/login", payload, {
   withCredentials: true,
   headers: {
     Accept: "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
   },
 });
 return response.data;
} catch (error) {
 throw error;
}
};
```

**Backend**

session.php

```php
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

cors.php

```php
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

kernel.php

```php
        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: One of the priciples of REST is to be stateless, so no session through cookies. Use jwt for that.

Comment: yes i am implementing a jwt but i store it as a cookie instead from the server side

Comment: The token need to be sent in the header as `authorization : Bearer {token}` to authenticate the user. In the login end-point,  return the jwt in the response. Then send it back with axios in the header for other end-points requiring authentification.